# How to explicitly solve the SDE $dX_{t} = tX_{t} + \sigma \cos t X_{t}dW_{t}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the stochastic ode $dX_{t} = tX_{t} + \sigma \cos t X_{t}dW_{t}$, where $W_{t}$ is the Wiener process. I am trying to solve it and not sure if my work is correct. My attempt:

Rearranging, we have $$\frac{dX_{t}}{X_{t}} = t + \sigma \cos t dW_{t}.$$ Then from Ito's Lemma, $dF(X_{t}) = F'(X_{t})dX_{t} + \frac{1}{2}F''(X_{t})(dX_{t})^{2}$ where $F$ is  a "nice" function, and putting $F(X_{t}) = \ln X_{t}$, we observe

$$d\ln X_{t} = \frac{dX_{t}}{X_{t}}  - \frac{dX_{t}^{2}}{2X_{t}^{2}} $$

And also, after some calculations, we find $dX_{t}^2 = \sigma^{2}X_{t}^2 \cos^{2}tdt$ since $dtdW_{t} = dt^{2} = 0$ and $dW_{t}^{2} = dt$. Then we have that, after some simplifying,

$$d\ln X_{t} = (t - \frac{\sigma^{2}\cos^{2}t}{2})dt + \sigma \cos t dW_{t}$$

Giving us, after integrating both sides:

$$\ln \frac{X_{t}}{X_{0}} = \int_{0}^{t} (u - \frac{\sigma^{2} \cos^{2} u}{2})\, du + \int_{0}^{t} \sigma \cos u\, dW_{u}$$

Can anyone please tell me if my solution is correct so far. Also, clearly the first integral on the right hand side is easily done. What about the second integral? Can it be done and hence can an explicit solution be written for this ode?

Comment: You can rewrite it in terms of $\int_0^t \sin(u) W_u du$, but I don't think this integral can be done in closed form either.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Ian

Comment: Looks correct. Use Ito's lemma on $X_t=X_0\exp( \text{ and so on and so forth } )$ to verify.

Comment: So it seems that the integral with respect to the Wiener process (second integral on the right) can't be done, right? @KurtG.

Comment: Not really. @Ian's trick is as good as it gets. You can however cheat a bit and say that there is another BM that you can time change to get this integral. See the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414995/analytical-solution-of-ou-process-with-scaled-time-transformed-wiener-process/4415368#4415368) where I do this in another context.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about the time change trick. That was always the most useful way of handling $\int_0^t f(s) dW_s$ for deterministic $f$ back when I was doing this stuff more often.

Comment: Ian, could you please elaborate on the time change trick? How is it done? @Ian

Comment: $\int_0^t f(s) dW_s = B_{\int_0^t f(s)^2 ds}$, where $B_u$ is another Brownian motion. Cf. https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/